# Selenium detect a popup dialog well, but cannot handle it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My configurations is as follows:

- Selenium: 3.14.1
- IEDriverServer: 3.9 -- x64
- IDE: IE 11
- Python 3.4.4

I'm just trying to accept a pop-up alert that opens. I have implemented the following code:

```
try:

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    print("Accept")

except TimeoutException:

    print("no alert")
```

The program detects the pop-up dialog, the message "Accept" is print, but not interfere with it. I'm no exception (message "no alert") or error program, the pop-up alert remains just open. The command `.dismiss()` does not work either.

I tried several different drivers for IE 11, but without success.

If anyone could help me this would be really appreciated :-).

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have indentation error.

So, your code should be:

```
try:

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    print("Accept.")

except TimeoutException:

    print("No alert.")
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: No, it's not that :-s